How to achieve TCP communication across network segments?
Suppose I have two hosts: A and B. Their network configuration is as follows:
A:
IP: 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

B:
IP: 192.168.12.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

A and B are connected to the same switch. On host A, the ARP reply of B can be obtained through arping.
So the physical links between A and B are connected. Can TCP communication be carried out?
==================================================================================
My job is network monitoring equipment maintenance, managing more than one hundred monitoring devices.
Host A represents my computer, and host B represents those monitoring devices.
B's network segment may be 192.168.12, 192.168.5, or something else.
I cannot modify B's network segments because my leaders also need to access them.
I know that I can add multiple IP addresses to A, for example, adding 192.168.12.5 can access devices in segment 12.
But I think this method is too troublesome. I need to add as many IPs as there are network segments for those monitoring devices.
I would like to ask, is there any other way to access those devices via TCP?

A and B are connected to the same switch You mean like the switch consists of two VLANs or are the two hosts literally in the same broadcast domain?

What you have is one Ethernet segment, shared by two IP subnets.
The "normal" way of achieving communication across IP subnets would of course be to use a router (gateway), but if you're asking this, I assume you're trying to bypass it for some reason.
Remember that IP on both devices needs to know how to send a packet to the other device. Meaning, although in your situation (shared Ethernet segment) it is possible to configure your computer so that it can directly talk to those subnets, simply by setting a larger subnet mask, that will not be enough because the devices still won't automatically know how to reply to you, as their subnet masks tell them otherwise.
For example, if you set host A's subnet mask to 255.255.0.0, it will indeed start directly making ARP for every 192.168.x.x address and will be able to send packets A→B. But even if you do this, device B still has its original 255.255.255.0 mask configured and won't consider A's 192.168.0.x to be "local" – it will attempt to reply B→A through whatever gateway it is configured to use.
Likewise, if you add a 'local route' or 'device route' on host A, telling it that host B's subnet is local, that will have the same effect of only letting you send packets A→B, but won't help with receiving them B→A at all.
(And since you're asking this question in the first place, I have to assume either that there is no gateway (router) at all, or that its firewall rules don't allow cross-subnet communications in the normal way.)
So with one-sided configuration you really can't take advantage of the shared segment here – if you want direct communication (without using a router), you have to keep adding addresses to host A for every single IP subnet that's on the same ethernet – or you have to talk to network administration so that they let you access those devices through the router/gateway (if there is one).
